# Euclidean Distance Calculation in C

Tags: php, mysql, c, euclidean-distance

I tried to calculate Euclidean distance in PHP using the following code.But the time it takes is very long. I want to test if I perform the same operation in C if it will be faster. The input datas should be passed from php whereas all other datas are stored in the mysql database. How can I make the operation fast as I have to calculate the distance of 30,000+ images having about 900 attributes each. So how can I make this calculation faster in C than in PHP? I have not programmed in C alot so any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

The query used in PHP for the distance calculation can be summarized as below:

```
SELECT tbl_img.img_id,
       tbl_img.img_path,
       ((pow(($r[9]-coarsewt_1),2))+(pow(($r[11]-coarsewt_2),2))+ ... +(pow(($r[31]-coarsewt_12),2))+
        (pow(($r[36]-finewt_$wt1),2))+(pow(($r[38]-finewt_$wt2),2))+(pow(($r[40]-finewt_$wt3),2))+
        (pow(($r[43]-shape_1),2))+(pow(($r[44]-shape_2),2))+ ...  +(pow(($r[462]-shape_420),2))+
        (pow(($r[465]-texture_1),2))+(pow(($r[466]-texture_2),2))+ ... +(pow(($r[883]-texture_419),2))+(pow(($r[884]-texture_420),2)))
       as distance 
FROM tbl_img 
INNER JOIN tbl_coarsewt 
ON tbl_img.img_id=tbl_coarsewt.img_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_finewt 
ON tbl_img.img_id=tbl_finewt.img_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_shape 
ON tbl_img.img_id=tbl_shape.img_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_texture 
ON tbl_img.img_id=tbl_texture.img_id 
WHERE tbl_img.img_id>=1 AND tbl_img.img_id<=31930 
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: the problem is not with the language but the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the language, as Arash Kordi put it. That SQL is going to be executed by your SQL server, and thanks to the algorithm used, that server going to be your bottleneck, not the language your script is written in. If you switch to C, you won't gain any significant speed, unless you also change your strategy.

Basic rules of thumb for optimization:

- Don't use database for your calculations. Use database to fetch relevant data and then carry out calculations in PHP or C.
- (Pre-calculated?) Look-up arrays: Analyze your data and see if you can build a look-up array of -- say -- pow() results instead of calculating each value again each time. This is helpful if you have lot of repetitive data.
- Avoid serialization -- Could you run multiple instances of your script parallel on different sections of your data to maximize throughput?
- Consider using server-side prepared statements -- they may speed things up a little.

Comment: I tried fetching all the datas first but the fetching process only takes more time than the above sql statement so I thought it is faster in mysql. And I had also read that Mysql is faster than PHP. How can I avoid serialization? Can you give some eg. As you can see I have 4 different table so performing calculation on the 4 tables seperately will it increase the performance?

Comment: They key to optimizing is to fix the algorithm. Anything else will not have massive effect on your performance, unless you're missing something basic like table indexes. What are you essentially trying to achieve? Why do you need the fast performance? Could you not just wait through the calculations once and store the results in a database table, from where you can then fetch the calculated values the next time you need them?